# module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target

Tags: compiling, kernel-modules

I tried to compile a module on Debian 10 (v4l2loopback) like this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback.git
cd v4l2loopback/
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

This gives me an error

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'v4l2loopback': Exec format error
```

I tried to find out what is wrong. (There are some issues regarding this problem, e.g. https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/208 or https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/296, but I think the problem is related to my system configuration, not to `v4l2loopback`).

**1. check `dmesg`**

I do not know what this means:

```
[   48.264449] v4l2loopback: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   48.264505] v4l2loopback: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   48.264610] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 00000000d85e721d, val ffffffffc0ba115b
```

**2. Check if kernel-headers match kernel installation**

From the following output, I think both match:

```
$ sudo modinfo v4l2loopback 
filename:       /lib/modules/4.19.0-2-amd64/extra/v4l2loopback.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Vasily Levin, IOhannes m zmoelnig <zmoelnig@iem.at>,Stefan Diewald,Anton Novikovet al.
description:    V4L2 loopback video device
depends:        videodev
retpoline:      Y
name:           v4l2loopback
vermagic:       4.19.0-2-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions

$ uname -a
Linux pingu1 4.19.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.16-1 (2019-01-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So this is not the problem.

**3. Is the toolchain used to build the module the same as the toolchain used to build the kernel?**

The kernel seems to be build with `gcc version 8.2.0`:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.19.0-2-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.2.0 (Debian 8.2.0-14)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.16-1 (2019-01-17)
```

I do not know how to find out what was used to build the module. My best guess is:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
```

So it is `8.2.0` versus `8.3.0`. This is a minor version change, which should not break anything.

**4. Run `depmod` before `modprobe`**

This did not make a difference. I think I did not make a difference because the module in concern has no dependencies.

Can someone help on what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and could resolve it by reinstalling the Kernel headers.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt remove --purge linux-headers-*
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.19.0-6-amd64-unsigned linux-headers-4.19.0-6-amd64
cd v4l2loopback/
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

Note that you need `sudo depmod`, otherwise the kernel module won't be found.

Hence, the crucial error from `dmesg` seemed to be

```
v4l2loopback: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

If I am right, you need an unsigned kernel, as `v4l2loopback` is not signed.

Comment: I have already said to run `sudo depmod` before `modprobe` .

Comment: You were right. However, the main problem was `module verification failed`, so when we discussed `depmod` it failed. Only when `module verifaction failed`was solved because of an unept kernel, I found out that `depmod` is indeed necessary.

Comment: Disabling the secure boot may solve the module signature problem, could you try it in the signed kernel? please.

Comment: It also works in the signed kernel `4.19.0-8-amd64`. Hence it is independent of signature. Maybe my setup was messed up...